# Represent Entity Framework Data in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, treeview

I am new to EF/WPF and I am trying to represent the following data in a TreeView

[image: EF]

The Quote object is the main object and the items must be editable. Which template can I use and how can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at WPF Binding tutorials
here is [firts](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html)
and there is [second](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx)

It should describes, what to do. 
Of course feel free, to ask about it.